# Run `php composer.phar dump-autoload` from code - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to run these command from code, but having some trouble finding out how.

- `php composer.phar dump-autoload -o`
- `php composer.phar require 'vendor/some-package'`
- `php composer.phar update 'vendor/some-package'`

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention, that I don't want to use the exec function because of potential risk and the fact that's blocked on most servers by default.

I did manage to download the .phar file from code, but not how to run these commands. I'm trying to build a friendly as possible solution and don't want use to dumpautoload manually after installing something etc.

Code to download

```
 $composerPath = base_path('composer.phar');
 copy('https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar', $composerPath);
```

Comment: Down voting without explaining why is of no use... Please provide information on why you down voted so I can adjust my question and make it better.

Comment: What are you actually trying to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a working solution. You can call these command with Symphony's process component.

```
$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process('php composer.phar autoload-dump');
$process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
$process->run();
```

Worked it out into a class:
https://codeneverlied.com/using-composer-from-code/

Answer (score 0):

you can run`composer global require "laravel/envoy=~1.0"`  to bring Laravel's envoy package into your project.  With envoy you can write something like

```
@servers(['localhost' => '127.0.0.1'])

@task('foo', ['on' => 'localhost'])
    php composer.phar dump-autoload -o
    php composer.phar require 'vendor/some-package'
    php composer.phar update 'vendor/some-package'
@endtask
```

but at some point the server will have to run `envoy run task`, this is also guessing on your question.  You may more elaborate more on what you are trying to actually do.

Answer (score 0):

cd /tmp

wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

chmod 755 composer.phar

php composer.phar --version